# webapi 2 - how to properly invoke long running method async/in new thread, and return response to client

Tags: c#, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api2

I am developing a web-api that takes data from client, and saves it for later use. Now i have an external system that needs to know of all events, so i want to setup a notification component in my web-api.

What i do is, after data is saved, i execute a `SendNotification(message)` method in my new component. Meanwhile i don't want my client to wait or even know that we're sending notifications, so i want to return a `201 Created / 200 OK` response as fast as possible to my clients.

Yes this is a fire-and-forget scenario. I want the notification component to handle all exception cases (if notification fails, the client of the api doesn't really care at all).

I have tried using `async/await`, but this does not work in the web-api, since when the request-thread terminates, the async operation does so aswell.

So i took a look at `Task.Run()`.

My controller looks like so:

```
public IHttpActionResult PostData([FromBody] Data data) {
    _dataService.saveData(data);
    //This could fail, and retry strategy takes time.
    Task.Run(() => _notificationHandler.SendNotification(new Message(data)));
    return CreatedAtRoute<object>(...);
}
```

And the method in my NotificationHandler

```
public void SendNotification(Message message) {
    //..send stuff to a notification server somewhere, syncronously.
}
```

I am relatively new in the C# world, and i don't know if there is a more elegant(or proper) way of doing this. Are there any pitfalls with using this method?

Comment: Why can't you use async/await? The framework should take care of this for you.

Comment: If i make my `SendNotification()` return `async Task`, i have to `await` the call in my controller class, and when i then return in my controller before my async method has finished, the async method terminates, and never finishes.

Comment: This sounds like the wrong behaviour. If you're using async, it shouldn't terminate before you want it to. Can you include the async code you've tried please?

Comment: I have discarded those changes a while ago, and VS has poor (none) local history. But basically i made the `SendNotification`method return `async Task` and called it from my controller method. Without the `await`keyword, it executes async, but the "main" thread terminates the async invocation. If i add the `await`keyword, and make my controller method `async` it probably does it async, but i'm not able to return a response to  the client before the awaited invocation is finished

Comment: The behaviour you've described is not correct. Your async method should not return before the await method is complete, that's the whole point of using the pattern. It waits for this code to return but does not block while doing so. If it's not waiting then it sounds like a problem in the code.

Comment: Yes of course. `await` 'says' it all, it should wait for a result of a method invocation. That is not want i want to achieve. I think i have just gotten `async/await` down the wrong pipe. Because what i actually want to do, is not necessarily to do anything async, merely do something in parallel independently from each other (return the response to the client, and invoke a method for another component to handle a message)

Comment: OK makes sense. Definitely check out Mark Walsh's answer if you want to leverage the framework otherwise RabbitMQ or Hangfire if you want to use a library. Good luck :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It really depends how long.  Have you looked into the possibility of QueueBackgroundWorkItem as detailed [here](https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2014/05/07/scheduling-background-jobs-from-an-asp-net-application-in-net-4-5-2).  If you want to implement a very fast fire and forget you also might want to consider a queue to pop these messages onto so you can return from the controller immediately.  You'd then have to have something which polls the queue and sends out the notifications i.e. Scheduled Task, Windows service etc.  IIRC, if IIS recycles during a task, the process is killed whereas with QueueBackgroundWorkItem there is a grace period for which ASP.Net will let the work item finish it's job.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I will give it a whirl.

Answer (score 2):

I would take a look on [Hangfire](http://hangfire.io/). It is fairly easy to setup, it should be able to run within your ASP.NET process and is easy to migrate to a standalone process in case your IIS load suddenly increases.
I experimented with Hangfire a while ago but in standalone mode. It has enough docs and easy to understand API.